# PowerAutomate Scheduling

Tags: power-automate

I want to schedule my Power Automate to be sent out on 3rd business day of each month. Can somebody help me and share their experience on how they do that?

I tried the formula under NO condition ...

```
@or(equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'ddd'),'Sat'),equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'ddd'),'Sun'))
```

but for some reason not working

Comment: You can't do it with expressions alone.  Do you have a premium licence?  If so, I can help you do it fairly quickly but it will require the use of a third party connector AND it will still need to be triggered everyday.

Comment: why not directly write 'em out? there's only 12 every year